# Javascript ECMAScript 5: arrays merging and deduction

Tags: javascript

**I have** got 3 arrays:

```
presentEntities = ['1', '2', '3'];
addedEntities = ['3', '4'];
removedEntities = ['2'];
```

**I need:**

1. Merge `presentEntities` with `addedEntities` and take into account possible duplicates (means I need a Set)
2. Deduct `removedEntities` from the result

**Expected result:**

```
['1', '3', '4']
```

**Question:** was is the true way to do that in javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an ECMAScript 5 compatible way:

```js
var presentEntities = ['1', '2', '3'];
var addedEntities = ['3', '4'];
var removedEntities = ['2'];

var uniqueEntities = addedEntities.filter(function(value) {
    if (presentEntities.indexOf(value) === -1) return value;
});

mergedEntities = presentEntities.concat(uniqueEntities);

var finalEntities = mergedEntities.filter(function(value) {
    if (removedEntities.indexOf(value) === -1) return value;
});

document.body.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(finalEntities);
```